# Choice of a data type for a Paquet join columns (i.e., keys)

Tags: hadoop, model, parquet, database-tuning

With RDBMS we usually use a **numeric** columns for keys (both foreign and primary), as it allows for a better *joined query* performance and smaller resource usage, in most cases, than other data types (like strings).

The question is, **what should be the data type of choice for the key columns in a Parquet tables**? Can we go like this:

```
SELECT * FROM parquet_table1 JOIN parquet_table2 ON t1_string_pk = t2_string_fk
```

**What is the best practice here?**

The reason for this question is that when loading data into a data warehouse, any numeric key column (for a target table) requires a key table lookup (*[source system, source key] -> surrogate key*), and the string key column does not; we may use source key concatenation to get us a string surrogate key value.